# How to create chromeless window?

Tags: c++, windows, user32

Currently I create window via command like

```
   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle,
                      WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
                      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

or this shall be defined via something in  `wcex.style` instead of my current   `wcex.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;` ?

Upadate: problem: I downloaded [chromeembeded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/downloads/detail?name=cef_preview_3.1082.566_windows.zip&can=2&q=) for windows and I try to get rid ow window chrome and border but what ewer I do it tends to look like this:

[image]

I wonder how to create chromeless window with CreateWindow?

Comment: You can't use WS_EX_TRANSPARENT where you have it. You must use the CreateWindowEx function and specify WS_EX_TRANSPARENT as the first argument.

Comment: Furthermore, that style only works for a child window.  What is the real intention here?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify any other style such as WS_OVERLAPPED or WS_BORDER alongside the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style, then it should be created without any border or title.